# Apache : wild card redirection rules

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, redirection

I have the below requirement for an apache redirection. When this url comes

`https://example.com/first-path/index.jsp?jpc=red`

it should go to.

`https://example.com/red`

Where `jpc` is a  constant value key but the string 'red' can be any string.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! [Server Fault is a site for information technology professionals](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) -- as such we have certain professional expectations when people ask a question here, and one of those expectations is that your question shows you did some **research**, found and **read the vendor documentation** and/or **tried a solution** before asking the internet for help. You're not expected to solve everything yourself, but then at least you can [write a great question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) that we can help you answer.

Comment: For Apache HTTPD that would typically be implemented with mod_rewrite rules. The official manual is here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/ and there are many other resources to be found as well